# Iterating through an array of strings, fetched from MongoDB

Tags: swift, mongodb

I'm using the [MongoKitten](https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten) library to fetch documents from mongoDB.

I have the following document in my mongoDB:

```
{
    ...
    foo: ["A", "B"]
    ...
}
```

I can query the db, but I can't loop through the `foo` array of the returned documents. For instance, let's say that I save the results of my query into `mongoDocs`.

```
for Doc in mongoDocs {
    print(Doc["foo"] as Any) // prints ["A", "B"]
    var tempFoos = [String]()
    for foo in Doc["foo"] { // gives error: Type 'Value' does not conform to protocol "Sequence"
        print("Foo: " + foo)
        tempFoos.append(foo)
     }
}
```

I understand the error. Basically, my `foo` array doesn't conform to the Sequence protocol that allows me to loop over it. But how do I fix that?

**Edit** - Here's the code I'm using to fetch the `mongoDocs`. I've printed the results and used other properties from them. I just can't seem to iterate through this array.

```
mongoDocs = try self.geographiesCollection!.find(matching: q, projecting: projection, limitedTo: 100)
```

Here's the [relevant function in the MongoKitten source code](https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten/blob/63321389439cb3749a3f2648ce2817931408ae0d/Sources/MongoKitten/Collection/Collection.swift#L256). The function returns `Cursor<Document>`

Comment: did you try casting mongoDocs as an array?

Comment: @Adam How did you obtain `mongoDocs`?

Comment: @JustinM, @Alexander: I updated my question to include my code to fetch the `mongoDocs`

Comment: @Adam what do `type(of: Doc)` and `type(of: Doc["foo"])` return?

Comment: @Alexander, I'm getting `Document` and `Value`, respectively.

Comment: @Adam Check out this [MongoKitten closed issue](https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten/issues/27) "returns an enum (Value) when subscripting a document." One of the framework devs explains how to properly handle this situation.

Comment: @JustinM, you're a lifesaver, thanks! If you submit as an answer, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: @Adam your welcome. I submitted an answer below. To save yourself some time in the future I highly recommend that f you run into an issue with a framework to check out the open/closed issues. You will usually find someone else who may have had a similar issue in the past and a way to solve it.

Comment: @JustinM, yeah, thanks so much. It was actually one of the first things I did. Must've just glossed over this one. I'm new to swift and couldn't tell if it was a language issue or a framework issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can check out how a framework dev explained handling this situation. [MongoKitten closed issue 27](https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten/issues/27)

here are some quotes from his explanation incase the link becomes invalid.

"MongoKitten BSON library always returns an enum (Value) when subscripting a document."

"A BSON array is really just a document with keys from 0 to x, so the enum case for array has a document as it's associated value. Because Value can also be, say, a double or a date, it doesn't conform to the Sequence protocol.

The easiest way to iterate over the array is by using the document convenience accessor on Value. This returns the underlying document if Value is either an array or document, or an empty document if it's something else. You can then iterate like this:"

```
for (key, val) in doc["vals"].document {
   print("Value is \(val)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into an array:

```
for Doc in mongoDocs {
    guard let arr = Doc["foo"] as? [String] else { continue }
    for foo in arr {
        // do your things
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the warning `Cast from 'Value' to unrelated type '[String]' always fails` on the line `guard let arr = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using [BSON 3](https://github.com/OpenKitten/BSON/tree/bson3). `Value` is an enum with multiple cases, which you can see [here](https://github.com/OpenKitten/BSON/blob/bson3/Sources/Value.swift#L84). Here's my stab at it:

```
for doc in mongoDocs {
    guard case Value.array(let fooArray)? = doc["foo"] {
        fatalError("doc[\"foo\"] is not an array")
    }

    print(fooArray)
}
```