# How to extract an array of Documents from a MongoKitten query

Tags: swift, mongokitten

I can't seem to retrieve an array of documents from a parent document using MongoKitten.

Returned document:

```
    {"updated":{"$date":"2016-01-16T17:58:45.171+11:00"},
 "name":"XXXX",
 "status":true,
 "_id":{"$oid":"57297a76b30bbf896e0a1c55"},

 "groups":[
    {"name":"Configuration Testing", 
     "allow_auto_approval":false, 
     "_id":{"$oid":"5699ea252529119457a40a67"}, 
     "expected_users":30, 
     "code":"632DZ0"
    },
    {"name":"Solution Demonstration", 
     "allow_auto_approval":false, 
     "_id":{"$oid":"5699ea252529119457a40a68"}, 
     "expected_users":50, 
     "code":"632GN1"}
 ]
 }
```

Swift code to iterate over array of sub documents:

```
let result = database.collection.findOne()

let groups = result["groups"]

for group in groups {
   print("group: \(group["code")")
}
```

I have also tried

```
   for (key, val) in result["groups"].documentValue {
            print("Value is \(val)")
   }
```

but this shows a syntax error

```
"Value of type 'Primitive?' has no member 'documentValue'"
```

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem is. Or why you would expect `result["groups"].documentValue` to work.

Comment: See here where this was the accepted answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263052/iterating-through-an-array-of-strings-fetched-from-mongodb

Comment: I see no reference to `documentValue` in that answer.

Comment: Did you look at the MongoKitten closed issue #27 https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten/issues/27

Comment: In any event I get the same error using `.document`

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is

```
for (key, val) in Document(doc["groups"]) ?? [] {
    print("Value is \(val)")
}
```

Thanks to https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten/issues/27#issuecomment-325623157